# Promise in for loop in promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, for-loop, promise

I have a bit of a messy problem I can't find a proper answer for. It's in firebase which doesn't support await and async.

At the moment, it works, but only runs once and doesn't loop.

```
return foo.bar(query);})
        .then((result) => {

            if (result == '0') {
               //do stuff
            } 


            else {
                var i;
                for(i = 0; i <= result; i++) {
                    return foo.bar(secondQuery);})
                    .then((secondResult) => {
                        //do other stuff                


                    })
                }

            }

        })
```

Comment: `return` will terminate the function after the first iteration. What do you want to achieve there?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

> The Promise.all(iterable) method returns a single Promise that
>   resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have
>   resolved or when the iterable argument contains no promises. It
>   rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

```
return foo.bar(query).then(result => {

  if (result == '0') {
    //do stuff
  } else {

    var i;
    var all = [];
    for (i = 0; i <= result; i++) {
      var p = foo.bar(secondQuery).then((secondResult) => {
        //do other stuff                
      });

      all.push(p)
    }

    return Promise.all(all);
  }

});
```

Comment: So my implementation is a little complicated. I did what you said in the context of my application, and have pasted the full code below, because it still seems to only run once. It doesn't loop.
https://pastebin.com/ReXD1G0e